# what is the minimal amount of questions to find the value of a value dependent probability dice

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

Assume I have a 6 sided dice with the probability rule: for each dice value (1 to 6) the chances of getting the value $x$ on a dice roll is $\frac{x}{21}$, e.g the chances to get 6 is $\frac{6}{21}$, 5 is $\frac{5}{21}$....

I know that the entropy of the cube is 2.3983. so this sets the lower boundary of the mean amount of yes/no questions to 2.3983 (correct me if i am wrong).

given a secret cube, what is the best set of yes/no questions to ask so that the mean questions amount is minimal?

one solution i thought of is first question: is the value even? if yes then start asking about even values in decreasing order until I hit the right number (so 6 then 4 and then i am done), same manner if the answer to the first question is no (meaning odd).

Comment: `given a secret cube` The "secret" word is a little confusing. We know that the probabilities are the stated ($i/21$), no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking for the optimal set of yes/no questions is the same as asking for the best prefix-free binary code.  And the answer is given by the [Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

In our case I get (there are other alternatives, but all have the same $L$)

```
6 - 11
5 - 01 
4 - 00
3 - 101
2 - 1001
1 - 1000
```

This give an average length $L=2.42857 > 2.3983$

In words, this would correspond to:

```
 Ask "Is the value 4 or 5?"
    If yes: Ask if it's 5.
    If no:  Ask if it's 6.
       If no: Ask if it's 3.
           If no: Ask if it's 2.
```

Your proposal amounts to

```
6 - 10
5 - 00 
4 - 110
3 - 010
2 - 111
1 - 011
```

which is not bad, but suboptimal: $L=2.47619$

Answer (score 0):

what about the following set of questions?

```
is the number in {1,2,3,5}?
   if not, is it 6? (yes = 6, no = 4)
   if yes, is it in {1,2,3}? (no = 5)
     if yes, is it in {1,2}? (no = 3)
       if yes, is it 1? (no = 2, yes =1)
```

my guiding principle is to always cut the probability space by half every step.

Comment: "my guiding principle is to always cut the probability space by half every step" That's not bad, but suboptimal (esentially https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano_coding )